# How to check when the network is unavailable in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have added some logic to handle the network is not unavailable but I have a hard time to trigger the error handler. I am using URLError networkUnavailableReason is it the right one?

```
DataService.shared.GetMyData(completion: {(result) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch result {
            case .success(let data):


                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                if let error = error as? URLError, error.networkUnavailableReason == .constrained  {

                    self.showAlert()
                }

                break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Why do you want specifically for unavailable Network? If the Server falls into a timeout, then you also get a failure, however in that case the Network is available. I would suggest to handle alle errors/failures the same way.

Comment: I think you will not have a failure response if network is unavailable. You should check it before begin the server request

Comment: how I can do that?

Comment: Apple specifically advises against performing preflight checks before network operations; network connectivity is volatile. Just because it is available now, Doesn't mean it will be in a millisecond  Just try the operation and handle any errors.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you send an article  or a blog post about topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NWPathMonitor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor), which is a network monitor, to check if the network is available. I used one like this, by creating a struct for it :

```
// make sure to import Network in your file when you do this
struct NetworkMonitor {
    static let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    static var connection = true
}
```

Then used it like this, wherever you want to start monitoring:

```
NetworkMonitor.monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
               if path.status == .satisfied {
                    print("connection successful")
                    NetworkMonitor.connection = true
                    // then respond to successful connection here, I used a notification and this connection bool
              } else {
                    print("no connection")
                    NetworkMonitor.connection = false
                    // respond to lack of connection here
               }
          }

          let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
          NetworkMonitor.monitor.start(queue: queue)
```